# How can I invoke a JUnit Parametrized test runner on a collection of generic types?

Tags: java, generics, junit, parameterized-unit-test

So I am trying to invoke the JUnit `Parameterized` test runner on a load of individual generic typed objects. The specific classes to be used are known to descendant classes.

Originally I managed to get a method which returns a `Collection<T>` for JUnit to work with, but then I realised JUnit actually requires a `Collection<T[]>` - I'm having trouble creating this array because of Java's reluctance/refusal to create arrays of generics.

```
protected static <T> Collection<T> someMethod(Class<T> someClass)
{
    Collection<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    T someBean;
    while (someCondition(...))
    {
        //Do some stuff to compute someBean

        result.add(someBean);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now JUnit requires an `Collection<T[]>` like this:

```
// (descendant class)
@Parameters
public static Collection<SomeActualClass[]> data()
{
    return someMethod(SomeActualClass.class);
}
```

So I want to change the return type by doing something like:

```
protected static <T> Collection<T[]> someMethod(Class<T> someClass)
{
    Collection<T[]> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    T someBean;
    while (someCondition(...))
    {
        //Do some stuff to compute someBean

        result.add(new T[]{someBean});
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately Java won't let me do this because you can't create generic arrays.

I'm tempted to put the statement as `result.add((T[])new Object[]{someBean});` but is this safe? or is there a better way?

Comment: "JUnit actually requires a Collection<T[]>" why does it require this? It seems kind of strange

Answer (score 0):

It's awkward as hell, but the following should work:

```
T[] theArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(someClass, 1);
theArray[0] = someBean;
```

Cf.:

```
public class Foo<T> {

    final T t0;
    final T t1;
    final Class theClass;

    public Foo(T t0, T t1, Class<T> theClass) {
        this.t0 = t0;
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.theClass = theClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T[] getStuffArray() {
        T[] theArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(theClass, 2);
        System.out.println(theArray.getClass().getName());
        theArray[0] = t0;
        theArray[1] = t1;
        return theArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Number[] stuffArray = new Foo<Number>(1, 2.5, Number.class).getStuffArray();
        for (Number s: stuffArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're *really really sure* that it's safe, you could skip `someClass` and just use `someObject.getClass()`, but then you run the risk that `someObject` is a subclass of `T` rather than `T` itself, which in the above case would get you an `ArrayStoreException` trying to put `2.5` into an `Integer[]`.

(Note though that if you get past that -- if you only store `Integers` -- java will let you get away with casting that `Integer[]` to a `Number[]`. Don't ask me why.)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use a `List<T>` and then use the `toArray(T[])` method, and you will get a `T[]`.

You can also create a generic List with only one element using `Collections.singletonList(T o)`

Comment: Unfortunately these don't help: `toArray()` returns an `Object[]` rather than `T[]` which is identical to `new Object[]{someBean}` as in my example, and `singletonList` returns a `List` rather than an array as expected by JUnit. The one-argument form `toArray(T[])` returns a `T[]` but you still have to create the generic array to pass into the `toArray` method, so it's no help...

Comment: toArray() returns Object[], toArray(T[]) returns T[]